# Test/Configure All NAT Scenarios(Full Cone,Port Restricted etc) by (1) .using iptables/ethernet/loopback interface

Tags: iptables, nat

**What I am trying to Achieve:**

Test/Configure All NAT Scenarios(Full Cone,Port Restricted etc) by (1) .using iptables (2) ethernet interface (3) loopback interface (Using only one machine)

## Set Up following configuration :

I am running one VM in a Linux BOX, and performed following configuration :

Linux BOX IP is : `192.168.0.4`

Linux Box *Virtual Box* Gateway IP is : `192.168.56.1`

Running Stun Server Binded on : `192.168.56.1` (Primary) and `192.168.0.4` (Secondary) on Linux Box

Running Stun Client on VM(Running on above Linux Server) at `127.0.0.1:2000` , and configured iptables rules to forward loopback interface traffic to ethernet interface (`192.168.56.102`) and vice versa.

## Expected Result

I should be able to configure each NAT Simulation via iptables/ethernet/loopback interface on which STUN Server running on Host and Stun Client running on VM, and it should tell the *type of NAT*

## Actual Result

iptables doing nothing with the packets in/out to loopback interface
socket *sendto* call fails with error : "error 22 invalid arguement" because socket has bind with `127.0.0.1:2000` and destination address is : `192.168.56.1`

## See below in short

```
[Loopback-Interface(127.0.0.1 :2000 / *Running STUN Client*/ VM) -->[*IPTABLES RULES TO/FROM*] <-- Ethernet-Interface(VM -- 192.168.56.102:2000) ==>|| ==> HOST(Gateway - 192.168.56.1:3478 - *Running STUN Server*)] ::
```

Examples Rules ::

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --source 127.0.0.1 --sport 2000 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.56.102 

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --source 127.0.0.1 --sport 2001 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.56.102 
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --destination 192.168.56.102 --dport 2000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1 

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --destination 192.168.56.102 --dport 2000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

**It Seems iptables doesn't pick packets from loopback interface**

References : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-redirect-127-0-0-1-to-192-168-1-113-a-818817/

Please let me know if any body can help on this.

Comment: @user671170 your Reference got b0rked. in addition, I truly don't understand what you're trying to draw there.

Comment: @user671170 : please post your routing table's routes (i.e. output from `netstat -rn`), I will try to reproduce your set up when I get enough item spare